# Android BroadcastReceiver onReceive function does not get called

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm trying to make a reminder app. The problem I have is that I can't get the BroadcastReceiver to work. The onReceive() function just doesn't get called.

Here is my AddActivity.java:

```
package tywele.remindme;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by Simon on 14.07.2014.
 * Diese Klasse baut das Layout und die Funktionalität zum Hinzufügen einer Erinnerung auf.
 */
public class AddActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private EditText reminderEditText;
    private TimePicker reminderTimePicker;
    private DatePicker reminderDatePicker;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_reminder_layout);

        //Färbt die ActionBar
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#009688")));

        reminderEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        reminderTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        reminderDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

        reminderTimePicker.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this));
    }

    /**
     * Erstellt eine neue Erinnerung und speichert sie in der Datenbank
     * Setzt den Alarm für die Erinnerung und ruft den BroadcastReceiver auf
     */
    public void OnReminderSubmitButtonClick(View view) {
        DatabaseHandler db = (DatabaseHandler) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("db");
        Reminder newReminder = new Reminder(reminderEditText.getText().toString(),
                reminderTimePicker.getCurrentHour(), reminderTimePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
                reminderDatePicker.getDayOfMonth(), reminderDatePicker.getMonth() + 1, reminderDatePicker.getYear());
        db.addReminder(newReminder);



        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, newReminder.getMonth());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, newReminder.getDay());
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, newReminder.getYear());

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, newReminder.getHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, newReminder.getMinute());
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent callNotification = new Intent(this, CustomReceiver.class);
        callNotification.putExtra("reminder", newReminder);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 101, callNotification, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

This is my CustomReceiver.java:

```
package tywele.remindme;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

/**
 * Created by Simon on 15.07.2014.
 */
public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        String notificationTitle = ((Reminder) intent.getSerializableExtra("reminder")).getText();

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_small_icon).setContentTitle(notificationTitle).setContentText(notificationTitle).build();
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
        System.out.println("Notification built");
    }

}
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="tywele.remindme">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

    <application
        tools:replace="android:icon"
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/remindme_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="DATABASE"
            android:value="remind_me.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="VERSION"
            android:value="1" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AddActivity"
            android:label="@string/add_reminder_text"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="CustomReceiver" android:enabled="true"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The onReceive() method never gets called. Please help me! :(

Comment: Remove the code from onReceive() and place a Toast in it and see if that works first.

Comment: Does not work. The toast is not displaying just as the `System.out.println()` I had in there.

Comment: Make sure newReminder.getMonth(), getYear(), etc. are returning the expected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify an [IntentFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html) for your `CustomReceiver`.

AddActivity:

Replace

```
Intent callNotification = new Intent(this, CustomReceiver.class);
```

with

```
Intent callNotification = new Intent("tywele.remindme.ACTION_EVENT_TIME");
```

Then in your manifest add:

```
<receiver android:name=".CustomReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action  android:name="tywele.remindme.ACTION_EVENT_TIME" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: That didn't work. I still don't get my notification at the specified time nor do I get the `System.out.println()` message in my log.

Comment: @Tywele also there is a dot missing in front of the name of the receiver. Or go with the full package name (probably android:name="tywele.remindme.CustomReceiver")

Comment: @Tywele are you sure the time is set right? try `System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000` instead of `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` just to test, or print the value

Comment: Ok the month was not set right. A different problem occurs now: When I set more than one reminder only the first reminder is displayed as a notification. For example: 1. reminder= "eating", 2. reminder= "sleeping". At both times the notification says "eating".

Comment: try using a different `requestCode`. ex. use the `eventId` from the database